# How to make that all fragments are retrieved by index?

Tags: c#

Good afternoon! I need to extract text from a specific word to a specific character. Here is the code

```
while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)  
{
    string lines = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
       
    int index1 = lines.IndexOf("color");
    int index = lines.IndexOf("}");
    if (index != -1) 
       builder.AppendLine(lines.Substring(index1, index));
       
    textBox1.Text = builder + "";               
}
```

The fact is that there are several such passages in the text. I need to extract all such passages from a word to a character. But it extracts only the first passage. How can I extract all passages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split `lines` by `color` as a delimiter and then find index of `}` from each split string,

```
string[] splitLines = lines.Split("color");
foreach(var splitLine in splitLines)
{
    int index = splitLine.IndexOf("}");
    if(index != -1)
      builder.AppendLine($"color{splitLine.Substring(0, index)}");
}
 textBox1.Text = builder.ToString() + "";
```

Comment: Thank you. And another question in each of these sections is the word "BORDER" how to make him count the number of these words in each of the sections .

Comment: you can try `.Coun()` from Linq, like `var countBorderWord = splitLine..Split(" ").Count(x =>x == "Border")`